# Rest API Parameters are not getting passed to method

Tags: rest-api

I defined rest API method as follows -

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/verifyaccount/v1/*') 
global class VerifyAccountService
{
    @HttpPost
    global static String VerifyAccount()
    {   
        return 'VerifyAccountResult ==> ' + RestContext.request.params.get('AccountName');
    }
}
```

and I am trying test it as follows - 
I know there is another way of testing this but I want to call it from another salesforce org and thats why I need to test it like this. and I did not specify any parameter to method itself because **I wanted this method to be flexible and not bound to parameters defined in this method only.**

**Salesforce documentation says** -

> 'If the Apex method has no parameters, Apex REST copies the HTTP
>   request body into the RestRequest.requestBody property. If the method
>   has parameters, then Apex REST attempts to deserialize the data into
>   those parameters and the data won't be deserialized into the
>   RestRequest.requestBody property.' [Source](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_methods.htm#heading_2_1)

```
Http httpProtocol = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setEndPoint('https://cs9.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/verifyaccount/v1/');
request.setMethod('POST');
String strbody = '{  "AccountName" : "Test Company", "Id" : "1234566" }';
request.setBody(strbody);
HttpResponse response = httpProtocol.send(request);
String jsonInput = response.getBody();
system.debug('===>'+jsonInput);
```

Output is "VerifyAccountResult ==> null "

Answer (score 3):

Your example has
RestContext.**request**.params.get('AccountName')

I think you need to use requestBody, which is a Blob.

```
@HttpPost
global static String VerifyAccount()
{   
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Blob body = req.requestBody;
    String bodyString = body.toString();
    // TODO: Extract the parameter from the string
    return 'VerifyAccountResult ==> ' + bodyString );
}
```

You could format `strBody` in you example as JSON and then use JSON.deserialize or JSON.deserializeUntyped to get the values out in Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Your input JSON

```
{
"AccountName": "Test Company",
"Id": "1234566"
}
```

Corresponding APEX Class for the above JSON data

```
public class Jsondata {  //Have as a separate or as an Inner Class

public String AccountName;
public String Id;

 }
```

The Modified code for your implementation

```
@HttpPost
global static String VerifyAccount(){   
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
Blob body = req.requestBody;
String bodyString = body.toString();

//Deserializing the data sent into concrete SFDC objects
    Jsondata jsonwrap =(Jsondata)JSON.deserialize(bodyString,Jsondata.class);


return 'VerifyAccountResult ==> ' + jsonwrap.AccountName);
}
```